# show labels for last 10 candles only

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to find highest high and show labels only for the last 10 candles.

Here's what've done so far, but i cant get it to show labels only for last 10 candles, it's either all or nothing.

```
highestHigh = highest(high, 20)
is_high = high >= highestHigh
Lookback = bar_index - 10

if is_high and bar_index > Lookback and barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, na, "HH: \n" + tostring(highestHigh), color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Is there a work around to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your labels in an array then loop thorugh your array and compare your label's x position with the current bar index. Delete the label if the difference is greater than your lookback variable.

An example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_remove_labels(lbl_arr, lb) =>
    temp_arr = array.new_label()
    len = array.size(lbl_arr)

    if (len > 0)
        for i=0 to len-1
            lbl = array.get(lbl_arr, i)
            idx = label.get_x(lbl)

            if ((bar_index - idx) >= lb)
                label.delete(lbl)
            else
                array.push(temp_arr, lbl)
    temp_arr

var label_arr = array.new_label()

lookback = 10

if (close > open)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, high, "Green")
    array.push(label_arr, lbl)

label_arr := f_remove_labels(label_arr, lookback)
```